# signalR client hangs on server re-publish via vstudio

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a simple setup based on the example code of signalR.

Client is a .net core console app.
Server is a.net core web app with signalR published to local IIS website.

Everything works fine in general.
if i stop/start the server using the IIS manager, 'reconnecting', 'reconnected' events do fire.

However if i re-publish the server ( asp.net app), via the visual studio- publish menu.. events are not fired on the client..and its not able to reconnect either. not even 'closed ' event. just sits there doing nothing.
i need to explicitly need to 'restart' the IIS website to get things going again.

Any ideas anyone what could be going on under the hood?

Comment: Have you customed anything in client and server to reconnect? I fail to reproduce your issue. If I restart from IIS, the client will fail to connect the server due to `Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Not Found'` Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: True, restart works fine for me as well.  My trouble is with "publish" action

Comment: IMO, this may caused by the long time during your publish process and the client is disconncted. If you want to keep the connection when the server is lost, you may try `try catch` block to reconnect by yourself.